# Transit visa at istanbul airport

Tags: visas, transit, customs-and-immigration, turkey

I am an Indian citizen. I need to go to Tbilisi (Georgia) via Istanbul (Turkey) from Berlin (Germany).

I booked the two flights separately from two different companies. Do I need a transit visa for Turkey?

I do not have a cabin baggage. I guess if I have a cabin baggage, I would have to pick up the baggage at the Istanbul airport and would need a visa because I have to pass the immigration first?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you have schengen visa and also visa to enter Georgia. I don't think you need transit visa at istanbul airport, if you are just changing planes.

To answer to your question whether you need transit visa in Istanbul: http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa

Its says there:

> Question: I will be flying to Europe. I know that our aircraft will
>   land in İstanbul. I am not planning to leave the transit lounge. Do I
>   need to get transit visa?
>
> Answer: If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you
>   are not required to have transit visa. Otherwise, you have to make
>   visa application to the nearest Turkish Representation. Contact
>   information of the said missions can be reached through www.mfa.gov.tr
>   (Ministry/Turkish Representations).

Also, refer to this official page: http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa

It says this:

> India: Diplomatic passport holders are exempt from visa for their
>   travels to Turkey up to 90 days. Ordinary, Special and Service
>   passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary,
>   Special and Service passport holders with a valid Schengen or OECD
>   member's visa or residence permit may get their single entry e-Visas
>   valid for one month via the website www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that
>   they meet certain conditions.

If you want to enter istanbul, just apply for e-visa online to enter istanbul.  Remember you collect baggage ONLY after passport control.

I am also indian passport holder, entered through istanbul airport several times needed no transit visa, to change planes to another destination within the terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Per Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   - Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
>     third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the
>     international transit area of the airport and have documents
>     required for the next destination

As you write, if having luggage to pick up you would need a visa.

However, the fact is, even if you don't, in practice most check-in staff will consider Istanbul your final destination if you're on separate tickets, and thus deny you boarding without a visa. This is largely because if something goes wrong with your connection, you not "insured" and the airline that flew you to Istanbul could end up having to take you back.